# Python dict over 3 billion records to store

Tags: python, arrays, database, dictionary

I have a dataset in a document (7.5 GB), ordered in arrays of 43200 x 86400 (meaningless) keys (over 3 billion) containing four floats (l1, l2, z, m). These floats are rounded to 6 decimal digits.

You can approach the data like:

```
stuff(y, x) 
>> (l1, l2, z, m)
```

Things are simplified here, but this is how it works. Y and X are zeo-based and, as stated, meaningless.

What I need to do is store these data the other way round, where l1 and l2 are meaningfull keys:

```
betterstuff(l1, l2)
>> (z, m)
```

Conversion itself is not the problem (although it might take a few days). The matter is: how do I store these data, so that they are approchable in the fastest way.

I would like to be able to approach them with a call like:

```
z, m = giveme(l1, l2)
```

I considered a **pickle**, but the isue is that this always loads completely in the memory.

I considered **shelve** (build upon pickle) but that can only handle a single key and we have double keys here.

How else? Some db or so?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use a DBMS. SQLite is more than enough for the task, and the reading and inserting phase won't take that long if you set things up correctly. Of course the requirement is that each pair (m,z) must be unique in the input file

Comment: It is not clear what is the format of the input file and how you read it. Numpy arrays? HDF5?

Comment: The current file is an NC-file. Slow!

Comment: @gimix can SQlite manage that many records? That would indeed be the easiest way.

Comment: @Jeex "The theoretical maximum number of rows in a table is 2**64 (18446744073709551616 or about 1.8e+19). This limit is unreachable since the maximum database size of 281 terabytes will be reached first"

Comment: For the numerical data stored as netCDF you may consider xarray. If you try to switch from numpy/netCDT floats to pure python you will need more than 4 x 24 x 3x10^9 bytes (300GB?) to store it in RAM. For not-so-numerical data parquet data sets work OK

Comment: Conversion into an SQLite db is running. Will take about 60 hours due to the slow approach to the NC source file. See where it takes me.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use-case I can recommend many things.

A DB is the obvious fix here as others have recommended.

But since things are relatively vague I'm going to assume:

- You don't want to use a Database
- Mainly struggle with OOM issues
- Care mostly about speed

Have you tried using [`polars`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/tree/main) with the `bigidx` feature flag?

Just `pip install polars-u64-idx` and put all your data in a polars dataframe.
Using the "bigger than memory" feature, you should keep very good speed while avoiding any OOM issues.

To start with, you'd have to have your document in a format that can easily be read by polars. CSV, JSON, etc...

Then assuming the following dataframe in Polars:

| l1 | l2 | z | m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.234598 | 1.111111 | 6.123789 | 1.234598 |
| 5.895478 | 2.222222 | 9.568712 | 1.234598 |
| 8.365968 | 3.333333 | 3.333333 | 5.895478 |

You'd be able to make a `giveme` function like so:

```py
import polars as pl

def giveme(df, l1, l2):
    data = df.filter(
        (pl.col("l1") == l1)
        & (pl.col("l2") == l2)
    )
    return data["z"].item(), data["m"].item()
```

Assuming there is always one and only one answer.
If not you'll have to edit the function or deal with those cases separately

Answer (score 0):

The polar module certainly is interesting.

The NC-file is now being processed into a SQlite db, to make the data better and faster approachable. NC is not specifically build for speed.

I'll see where I'll take it from there.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Fun conclusion. After all the testing with SQLite, MariaDB (on webserver) and more, the netCDF4 (NC) file is still the fastest ;-) So, I stick to that. It was however educational again.